# Rerender RichFaces error message after ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I am using custom ajax-called javacode that does some processing on the server. In this process various errors can occure that I add to the `FacesContext` via `addMessage()`. 
I want to display these messages in the same `<rich:messages>`-tag that I use for my validation errors.

Do you know a way to display these messages in the `<rich:messages>`-tag after the ajax-request completed?

My initial idea was adding 
`<a4j:jsFunction name="richDisplayError" reRender="messages" />`
to the markup and calling richDisplayError when the request completed, but it seems the messages panel is rerendered empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<rich:messages>` has `ajaxRendered`set to `true` by default. So the problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps:

- you are redirecting, instead of forwarding, and the messages are lost
- you aren't actually adding the messages (check with debug)
- you are having different/lacking views/subviews

Comment: I think ajaxRendered is useless in this case, since I am making the ajax call via the a4j framework, but with custom functions. Is that the reason, how long do the messages live? are they lost when i fire another call?

Comment: `<a4j:jsFunction` is still the a4j frameweork.

Answer (score 2):

For example, in your page:

```
    <a4j:commandButton value="Action"
           limitToList="true" 
           action="#{mybean.action}"
           reRender="mymessages">
    </a4j:commandButton>
    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
       <h:messages id="mymessages"  />
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

then in you bean:

```
public void action(){                         
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("hello world")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need 3 things :**

**1st** : declare your error message, in the "\resources\bundle\errorMessages.properties" file, like this :

```
errorMsgToDisplay.errName = Your Error Message Here
```

**2nd** : declare your BUNDLE variable in the class code :

```
private static final ResourceBundle BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/bundle/errorMessages");
```

**3rd** : Display the message (after an condition for example )

```
if  ( condition ) {
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
BUNDLE.getString("errorMsgToDisplay.errName"),
BUNDLE.getString("errorMsgToDisplay.errName")));
}
```